# Continue execution on Database server connection error / Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, server, connection

I have 2 databases in different server that shows the information in a view (I have 2 database connections):

Here is the image:
[image: Imgur]

When I shutdown the MySQL server of one of them, I want that the app continues showing the other table, but instead of that, the app crashes:

Here is the error image:

[image: Imgur]

I changed the following line:

```
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
```

To:

```
'db_debug' => FALSE,
```

But continues crashing.

There are something to handle the MySQL connection errors to prevent that the app crashes?

I'm thinking in handle the error with a try-catch in my model construct:

```
public function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->database();
  $this->micucea = $this->load->database('micucea', TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Hm. If you're taking the server down, which the application relies on to show data, isn't that a planned outage, and the app should be down as well? Only showing half the expected info to users could be construed as giving them inaccurate or incomplete info, without their knowledge. Taking the server offline should be pretty rare. What's the actual real-world scenario here which you're trying to deal with?

Comment: Also, catching and squashing all DB connection errors will blunt your ability to detect an _unexpected_ outage, unless perhaps you redirect the exception info to a log and have a way to notify the support team as well.

Comment: Precisely what I want to achieve, that when a server shutdown replace it with anoter that contains a mirror database that will contain a recent backup, but first I must deal with the errors that CodeIgniter returns, then implement what I mentioned.

Comment: if you're only going to be replacing it with a mirror, it shouldn't take long...so just take the CodeIgniter site down for a few minutes at the same time. Problem solved.